# Configuring json parser to parse escaped json string in json

Tags: json, parsing

Assume you have the following json snippet

```
{
    "topic":"foo",
    "payload":"{\"type\":\"String\",\"value\":\"44\"}",
    "type":"ItemStateEvent"
}
```

At first glance it seems that `payload` has been converted to a json string twice. Naive approach would be calling the parsing function twice on this entire snippet. First time on the entire thing and the second time on the `payload` field.

Now for the question: How do you configure parser of your choice so it would do the menial work for you?

Comment: Just in my opinion - you don't. a) I don't think any parser was writting to support such scenario b) fix the data on the source. If the source is not yours, try to kindly ask to provider to fix it. If this is an API there is strong suspicion, other clients will struggle as well. Possibly it will get fixed and then you will have to change your code.

Comment: Fair enough. Regarding the source: it's an API i had found on the internet and just decided to inspect how it works. It's by no means "documented", in a sense, so I doubt that notifying them will do any good. Cheers though.

Comment: What if this is a coding test and the data is what it is, and the intention is to test how do you process JSON in escaped form?

Comment: @WesternGun No, this was an actual external interface that I had to deal with. But I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), java json parsing library, seems to have support per field deserializers. As a result, you can add `@JsonDeserialize(using = NestedDeserializer.class)` to the particular "nested" json field. `NestedDeserializer` is an implementation of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer`. Currently I'm playing around with the following implementation:

```java
    @Override
    public LinkedHashMap<String, String> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper m  = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec(); // am I sure that codec will always be ObjectMapper?
        TextNode textNode = m.readTree(p);
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> datum = m.readValue(textNode.asText(), LinkedHashMap.class);
        return datum;
    }
```

What the snippet does is it deserializes the current token into string and just runs it through the parser a second time.